# Elasticsearch Highlight : Java not highlighting the field

Tags: elasticsearch, highlighting

I am a rookie to elastic search.

I have learnt about the mapping and settings for highlighting.
From the document, in the field I have used the property "store:yes" in the raw field.But I dunno whether I'm giving in the right place or not.

My mapping:

```
"mappingtype":
{
    "_timestamp": 
    {
        "enabled": true         
    },
    "properties":
    {
        "products":
        {
            "type":"nested",
            "include_in_parent": true,
            "properties":
            {
                "productTitle":
                {                   
                    "type" : "string",
                    "fields" : 
                    {
                        "my_ngram_title" : 
                        {
                            "type":"string",
                            "index_analyzer": "my_ngram_analyzer", 
                            "search_analyzer": "default" 
                        },
                        "snowball_title" : 
                        {
                            "type":"string",
                            "index_analyzer": "snowball_analyzer", 
                            "search_analyzer": "snowball_analyzer" 
                        },
                        "raw" : 
                        {
                            "type" : "string",  
                            "store": "yes",                         
                            "index" : "not_analyzed"
                        },
                        "lowercase_title" : 
                        {
                            "type":"string",
                            "index_analyzer": "lowercase_analyzer"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    }   
}
```

Then in Java, while the query formation I have used the following fields.

```
   .setHighlighterPostTags("</span>")
   .setHighlighterPreTags("<span class='highlight'>")
   .addHighlightedField("products.productTitle.raw")
```

It was indexed perfectly and while searching I'm getting the search results perfectly.

But in the search results, results.getHighlightFields() is always null.

Also I need an example for the below scenario.

indexed record List : ['apple','orange','green apple','pineapple']

search keyword : "app"

Highlighting should be :

```
<span class='highlight'>app</span>le
green <span class='highlight'>app</span>le
pine<span class='highlight'>app</span>le
```

Is that anyway to acheive the above using elasticsearch highlighting??